# Ubuntu 18.04 Ethernet Unclaimed

Tags: networking, 18.04, ethernet

I've just installed Ubuntu on my computer and it's refusing to connect to ethernet. I've tried installing new drivers and updating the kernel to no avail.

````
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8125 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7d18
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at a3200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Memory at a3210000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=32 Masked-
    Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [148] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [168] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
    Capabilities: [178] Transaction Processing Hints
    Capabilities: [204] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [20c] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [21c] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0002 Rev=4 Len=100 <?>
    Kernel modules: r8169

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a3200000-a320ffff memory:a3210000-a3213fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:5
       logical name: wlx984827e17428
       serial: 98:48:27:e1:74:28
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu ip=172.26.104.151 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn```
````

Answer (score 0):

Support for RTL8125B was added in kernel version 5.9. So use a recent enough kernel version, or if this is no option use r8125 driver package instead.